# Hiding the Legend in this Graph

Tags: r, data-visualization, legend

I made this graph to demonstrate the progress being made by an optimization algorithm (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/132872_620c10f340f348b88453d75ec99960ff.html):

```
library(GA)
data("eurodist", package = "datasets")
D <- as.matrix(eurodist)


tourLength <- function(tour, distMatrix) {
   tour <- c(tour, tour[1])
   route <- embed(tour, 2)[,2:1]
   sum(distMatrix[route])
}

#Firness function to be maximized

tspFitness <- function(tour, ...) 1/tourLength(tour, ...)

GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D,
          min = 1, max = attr(eurodist, "Size"), popSize = 50, maxiter = 5000,
          run = 500, pmutation = 0.2)

plot(GA)
```

- The "legend" seems to be obscuring the graph - is it somehow possible to hide the legend?

Normally, graphs that are made using Base R and GGPLOT2 libraries can have their legends disabled pretty easily - but since the graphing function being used here is from a different library, I am not sure if it is possible to disable this legend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:
`plot(GA, legend = FALSE)`

P.S, if you are not familiar with a package function I always find it helpful to look up the R-documentation in the console using `??GA::plot`